# Customizing the page control for jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables.  I would like to customise the appearance of the page control so that it is clearer what the currently selected page number is.  I would like to either:

Have the currently selected page number enclosed by square brackets eg if page 2 was currently selected, 1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7  OR

Have the page numbers that are not selected underlined

But I’m unsure how to do this or if it is possible.

Comment: a bit of you code would be nice. I would have targeted the class of the selected page, if that differs from the others?

Comment: what version of datatables? 1.9.x / 1.10.x ?

Comment: Are you thinking of the pagination, generally on the bottom right of the table? If so have a look here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html You can also roll your own quite easily.

Comment: davidkonrad it is the latest version downloaded a couple of days ago v1.10

Comment: annoyingmouse yes I am talking about the pagination thanks for the link  but I'm unsure how to make this particular customisation.  Especially the square brackets as I don't think I can do it via css.  Maybe the underlining can be done via css if I can figure out the correct class to use.